# How to increase the size of an image by clicking it in handlebars?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, node.js, handlebars.js

I am using node.js with the handlebars template engine. Currently, the thumbnail images from the database are displaying at a width and height of 70 which is specified in the code. See below. How can I allow the user to click on the image in handlebars and see a larger rendition of the photo?
The current images are too small to see but I would only like for them to be increased upon clicking them.

I am using handlebars....so a variation of this would help...(without "onClick=" method as I am using node.js and it won't work)

```
<style>
img.std {
    height: 10%;
}
img.big {
    height: 40%;
}
</style>

<img id="img" class="std" onClick="(this.className=='std')?this.className='big':this.className='std'" src="/uploads/{{photo_image}}">
```

Comment: Can't you just use `img:active { height: 40% }` to resize when gets focus?

Comment: Ok, it's said that `:active` isn't working on images, maybe you need some CSS checkbox hack for that without javascript.

Comment: Active works but not the way I thought: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VPjdqQ CSS checkbox hack is the way to go.

Comment: Give me an example of this "checkbox hack" please@Taha Paksu

Comment: Here: https://codepen.io/juliankern/pen/xpWqZw it uses the `:checked ~` selector to select the sibling of an selected and visually hidden checkbox. That's why it's called a hack.

Comment: and you can use radio inputs to only make one picture big on every click.

Comment: not working for me....I need the example specific to my case please @Taha Paksu

Answer (score 1):

You can add an IIFE type function, and use an arrow function so the `this` keyword refers to the image:

```css
.container{
   height: 200px;
   border: solid 1px gray;
}

img.std {
  height: 60%;
}

img.big {
  height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img id="img" class="std" onClick="(() => {
      this.className = this.className === 'std' ? 'big' : 'std';
    })(); return false;" src="http://placekitten.com/200/200">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite easily with jQuery with:

```
$(document).on('click','img',function(){
   if (this.id == "img") {
       this.className=='std' ? this.className = 'big' : this.className='std';
   }
});

<img id="img" class="std" src="/uploads/{{photo_image}}">
```

I would suggest to use unique id for the tag to avoid future ambiguity (potential bugs).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the checkbox hack implemented to your code:

```css
.imgcontainer {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: stretch;
}

.imgcontainer input[type='radio'] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.imgcontainer input[type='radio'] + img.std  {
  height: auto;  
  width: 100px;  
}

.imgcontainer input[type='radio']:checked + img.std {  
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgcontainer">
  <input type="radio" name="imgcontainerradio">
  <img id="img" class="std" src="http://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
</div>
<div class="imgcontainer">
  <input type="radio" name="imgcontainerradio">
  <img id="img" class="std" src="http://placeimg.com/640/480/arch">
</div>
<div class="imgcontainer">
  <input type="radio" name="imgcontainerradio">
  <img id="img" class="std" src="http://placeimg.com/640/480/nature">
</div>
```

Comment: Which exact file, should I put the jquery code?Should it go in the main.js/app.js file or the gigs.handlebars file?                  
               $(document).on('click','img',function(){
   if (this.id == "img") {
       this.className=='std' ? this.className = 'big' : this.className='std';
   }
});

<img id="img" class="std" src="/uploads/{{photo_image}}">